# Alias for python3 working on SSH but not in browser with PHP?

Tags: python-3.x, web-hosting

I'm working in a shared hosting environment that came with Python 2.6 as a default. I used SSH to install Python 3.4, as well.

When I use the alias `python3` to execute the script, it runs perfectly.
But in the browser, where I use PHP to call the Python script, it returns the error: `python3 command not found`. If I use only the command `python`, it uses the 2.6 version, and the script doesn't work.

I can't restart the server because it's shared.

Is there a way to work around this?

PHP SCRIPT THAT CALL PYTHON3 SCRIPT:

```
<?php

$command = "python3 proccess.py 2>&1";

?>
```

Comment: How are you calling the script in your PHP code? Does the webserver have the right permissions to access and execute the file? Please update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would include, at the very least, the section of code where you call the script, and the file permissions (`ls -l`) of the folder under which your script is stored.

Comment: Is your `python3` alias actually an `alias` or a `symlink`. Because if it's just a bash alias in your `~/profile` or whatever, then obviously it will not be available system-wide to other users/your web app

Comment: @PyPingu the alias was created like this: alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.4'... and works fine in ssh client like putty

Comment: can you try changing the command to `~/.bashrc && python3 proccess.py 2>&1` If `~/.bashrc` is the file where you have defined the alias.

Comment: This way, you shall be able to use all the aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you run in PHP through webserver the PATH variable is different. So there are two ways to solve it

**Option 1**

Get the path from shell using `echo $PATH` and use the same in script

```php
<?php

$command = "PATH=/a:/b/c python3 proccess.py 2>&1";

?>
```

**Option 2**

Use the absolute path for python3. Run `which python3` and the path you get in that use that in your script

```php
<?php

$command = "/usr/bin/python3 proccess.py 2>&1";

?>
```

Comment: >>> sys.path
['', 
'/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python34.zip', 
'/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4', 
'/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', 
'/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
'/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Comment: Then try like `$command="PATH=/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python34.zip:/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4:/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux:/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload:/home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages python3 proccess.py 2>&1"`. Also make sure you run the php cli first and once fixed go to the web server way

Comment: `$command="env && ls -alh /";`, run this in your php code and then add the output to the question. I think the apache may be running under chroot of `/var/www` so it will not see anything outside of it

Answer (score 1):

You can change the command to:

```
<?php

$command = "~/.bashrc && python3 process.py 2>&1";

?>
```

Given `~/.bashrc` is the file containing alias', or use the corresponding alias file. This way, you shall be able to use all the aliases

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bash alias in your script. That isn't going to be accessible to your web app in a non-interactive shell. [And you don't want to do that anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases).

Create a symlink which will be available to anyone, anywhere:

`ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3`

**EDIT:**
Of course you can also just specify the full path in your PHP command:

```
<?php

$command = "/path/to/your/python3.4 proccess.py 2>&1";

?>
```

Comment: it returns: ln: `creating symbolic link /usr/bin/python3: Permission denied`

Comment: Well then run it with `sudo`. If you were able to install `python3.4` there I assume you have that permission?

Comment: sudo is not available in the server.. and apt-get is also not available

Comment: Well how did you install `python3.4` on that path??

Comment: using wget like posted in this link [link](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server/)

Comment: So your python3.4 is actually installed at `$HOME/.local` and not `/usr/bin`?

Comment: yes, seems it is, since is a shared hosting service, and I cant install things in some folders

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to specify the absolute path to your `python3.4` as I suggested in my edit?